# Failed to execute 'replaceState' on 'History'

Tags: angular, nginx, angular-universal

When google index my angular web application. It can't see the pages and in the console I have this error :

SecurityError: Failed to execute 'replaceState' on 'History': A history state object with URL 'https://MYDOMAIN/universe/' cannot be created in a document with origin 'https://webcache.googleusercontent.com' and URL 'https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:YlVK5uwbqWcJ:https://MYDOMAIN>/universe+&cd=2&hl=fr&ct=clnk&gl=fr'.

But I don't understand the error. Is that mean I have to allow cross origin for webcache.googleusercontent ?

I'm currently using angular universal and nginx as a reverse proxy.

Answer (score 1):

If you want your history to work when accessing your side from google's cache, you need to use relative a URL when you call `pushState`. AFAIK, there is no cross origin setting that will change this.

> The new URL must be of the same origin as the current URL; otherwise, pushState() will throw an exception

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API

You could use the hashLocation strategy instead of default path location strategy (https://angular.io/guide/router#appendix-locationstrategy-and-browser-url-styles). This *should* fix the problem

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
  BrowserModule,
  RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { useHash: true }) 
],
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but actually I'm using only relative url. All my urls are set in the angular router.

Comment: OK, I thought it was your own code. But then, do you have to worry about google's cache? For me, the requested uRL is when trying to access google's cached version of your website, not when google crawlers are accessing your website

Comment: Actually, the issue is not really google cache. My issue is that when google crawl my website it gets the html because i'm using angular universal for server side rendering, but when I look into the google search console how google see my website the page is completly blank even if the html is present. Then, I clicked on google cache to see my page and at the first rendering the page is displayed and then when the js files are processed the pages become bank and throught this error. By the way, I don't want to use hashlocationstrategy.

Comment: Ok, maybe you should open another question then. The cause for the error you reported is specifically due to using google cache.